# FullCalender v5 show/hide weekends via toggle button

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I know how you can initially show or hide Sat/Sun on the calendar by setting:

`weekends: true,`

If I use a toggle button what do I call to change it interactively?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Comment: And then you might have to tell the calendar to re render, I'm not sure

Comment: Thank you.    calendar.setOption('weekends', false);

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the document reference @ADyson.  Not sure why I didn't see the dynamic options.  Didn't need to re-render.

`calendar.setOption('weekends', false);`